# How to calculate moving average in spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to calculate a moving average in a spark structured streaming in terms of rows preceding and not time-event based.

Kafka has string messages like this:
device1@227.92@2021-08-19T12:15:13.540Z

and there is this code

```
Dataset<Row> lines = sparkSession.readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "users")
                .load()
                .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
                .map((MapFunction<Row, Row>) row -> {
                    String message = row.getAs("value");
                    String[] newRow = message.split("@");
                    return RowFactory.create(newRow);
                    }, RowEncoder.apply(structType))
                .selectExpr("CAST(item AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS DOUBLE)", "CAST(timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)");
```

The above code reads stream from kafka and transforms string messages to rows.

When i try to do sth like this:

```
WindowSpec threeRowWindow = Window.partitionBy("item").orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow(), -3);

Dataset<Row> testWindow = 
lines.withColumn("avg",  functions.avg("value").over(threeRowWindow));
```

I get this error:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;

Is there any other way to calculate the moving average as every message is coming and updating it as new data comes from stream? Or any non time-based operation is by default not supported to spark structured streaming?

Thanks

Comment: The error states not. That is a limitation due technical reasons.

Comment: I think (and haven't tested) that you'd have to write a stateful streaming query with `flatMapGroupsWithState`.